# Laravel 5.4 form post and save() don't work

Tags: forms, laravel, post, eloquent, save

I have problem with submitting data into database. Database works fine, as I can seed data into it and display data from it. I am suspecting that there is something wrong with post form, as I don't get any errors, it is like post doesn't reach controller at all. Here are the files:

view:

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('title') Homepage @endsection

@section('content')
    <h1>Homepage:</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad architecto aut consectetur debitis deleniti dolore ducimus, eaque ex, harum itaque laudantium nobis odit, officiis quae rem saepe sunt unde veritatis!</p>




    <div style=" width: 100%; text-align: center; display: inline-block;">

        @foreach($actions as $action)
            <a href="{{route('niceaction',['action'=>lcfirst($action->name)])}}"><h3>{{ $action->name }}</h3></a>
            <br>
        @endforeach

    </div>

    <div>
    <form action=" {{ route ('add_action') }}" method ="post">
        <label for="name">Enter name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name"/>
        <label for="niceness">Niceness level:</label>
        <input type="text" name="niceness" id="niceness"/>
        <button type="submit" >Do a nice action!</button>
       <input type="hidden" value="{{csrf_token()}}" name="_token"/>
    </form>


    </div>
@endsection
```

route:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function() {

    Route::get('/', [
        'uses' => 'NiceActionController@getHome',
        'as' => 'home'
    ]);


    Route::group(['prefix'=> 'do'], function(){

        Route::get('/{action}/{name?}', [
            'uses' => 'NiceActionController@getNiceAction',
            'as' => 'niceaction'
        ]);



        Route::post('/add_action', [
            'uses' => 'NiceActionController@postInsertNiceAction',
            'as' => 'add_action'
        ]);

    });

});
```

and controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;


use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\NiceAction;

class NiceActionController extends Controller {

    public function getHome() {
        $actions = NiceAction::all();
        return view ('home', ['actions' => $actions]);
    }

    public function getNiceAction ($action, $name = null) {

        if ($name === null ) {
            $name = 'you';
        }
        return view ('actions.nice', [
            'action' => $action,
            'name'=> $name
            ]);
    }

    public function postInsertNiceAction (Request $request) {


        $this->validate($request, [
            'action' => 'required',
            'name' => 'required|alpha',
            'niceness' => 'required|numeric'
        ]);


        $action = new NiceAction();
        $action->name = $request['name'];
        $action->niceness = $request['niceness'];
        $action->save();

        $actions = NiceAction::all();
        return view ('home', ['actions' => $actions]);

    }

    private function transformName($name){
        $prefix = 'KING ';
        return $prefix.strtoupper($name);
    }
}
```

Comment: it seems like your form just doesn't pass validation. you missed required `action` field

Comment: Yes that's it! Thank you very much, I knew it was something trivial, just couldn't find it.